# Google API - request for token from Oauth2 returns “invalid_request” with HTTP code 400

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I know same question has been asked many times but even after following each and every post as well trying various suggestions, I am still facing `invalid_request` error.

I am able to get code successfully from Google API and when I am trying to access `accessToken` , I am getting this error and HTTP code being sent from Google API is `400`.

I have already tried and compared my data with [oauthplayground](https://code.google.com/oauthplayground/) and seems everything is same

Following data is being sent from my Application to Google API

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?
scope=openid+profile+email
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fsavealifetoday.org%2Fblood_donors%2FoAuthCallBackAction%3Fservice_provider_name%3D
&approval_prompt=force
&client_id=193214746340-ea0nq5alpst82n2fno13s9j21pn4f4pf.apps.googleusercontent.com
```

### Access Token URL

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token?
scope=openid+profile+email
&client_secret=***********
&grant_type=authorization_code
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fsavealifetoday.org%2Fblood_donors%2FoAuthCallBackAction%3Fservice_provider_name%3D
&code=4%2F8veoAnihzkao58oWvZaRShn5nhYg.0to7Or-lHPwRXE-sT2ZLcbTblHXFhgI
&client_id=193214746340-ea0nq5alpst82n2fno13s9j21pn4f4pf.apps.googleusercontent.com
```

But When Application is trying to fetch data over the network, I am getting exception

```
SEVERE: Error while fetching access token for Google..
OAuthProblemException{error='invalid_request', description='null', uri='null', state='null', scope='null', redirectUri='null', responseStatus=0, parameters={}}
```

I am using `URLConnectionClient` to establish network connection

Comment: What happens if you take out the grant_type?

Comment: @lumpynose: Same issue...still getting this error `OAuthProblemException{error='invalid_request', description='null', uri='null', state='null', scope='null', redirectUri='null', responseStatus=0, parameters={}}`

Comment: Do you receive response after first request? And does error happen only after the second request?

Answer (score 3):

Go through the OAuth flow using the OAuth playground https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/.

Then compare what is being sent with your own.

Note that it needs to be an HTTP POST. The code you posted looks like a GET.

Also, your redirect URL looks a little odd. Is that **exactly** the same URL that you registered in the API console? This is isn't your current error, but will probably become your next one ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the update, Yes I have same redirect URL, since few other OAuth provider do not allow localhost ;). I have already seen it on playground and seems like everything is fine.I am doing HTTP POST

Comment: I getting the error till now. I have matched with oauthplayground. Its same.  What to do?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you forgot to send 'state' parameter here (it is mandatory!):

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?
scope=openid+profile+email
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fsavealifetoday.org%2Fblood_donors%2FoAuthCallBackAction%3Fservice_provider_name%3D
&approval_prompt=force
&client_id=193214746340-ea0nq5alpst82n2fno13s9j21pn4f4pf.apps.googleusercontent.com
```

In Java code you can generate it in a way like this:

```
String state = new BigInteger(130, new SecureRandom()).toString(32);
```

So you request should look like this:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?
scope=openid+profile+email
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fsavealifetoday.org%2Fblood_donors%2FoAuthCallBackAction%3Fservice_provider_name%3D
&approval_prompt=force
&client_id=193214746340-ea0nq5alpst82n2fno13s9j21pn4f4pf.apps.googleusercontent.com
&state= {insert_here_generated_state}
```

And also I don't know if it is necessary to send a 'scope' parameter in "Access Token URL".